# iPad/iPad2 - PDF page rendering speed

Tags: ipad, pdf, performance, font

I would like to know how long (in milliseconds) does it take for the iPad/iPad2 to render a PDF page. Every page and every PDF are different, of course. I am interested in average figures if you have any or can measure it, for any PDF's that are technical books.

Comment: Without a very precise definition of the content of the page and the app used to render it, any answer you might get is kind of pointless (because you can't apply it to any other PDF page). What are you needing this for?

Comment: who is so kind to perform a test can use this free pdf: http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/0/A/50A39509-D015-410F-A8F2-A5511E5A988D/Microsoft_Press_ebook_Programming_Windows_Phone_7_PDF.pdf (any optimized app is good for the test)

Comment: Measured from when til when? Downloading took ages, rendering/scrolling was immediately.

Comment: apps often cache the pages in the neighbourhood so you should measure the time it takes to jump to a far page

Comment: Making the resulting measurement even more unrealistic. Besides, even with jumping the pages get displayed immedately with iBooks, there is no way to measure this exactly without instrumenting the application